# AWS AppSync mutation using Lambda and API-Key

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-appsync

I have set up an AppSync API and everything is working fine from the client side (mobile App). Now I want to add mutation by a Lambda function to add items to the dynamoDB table(resolver). I am using cognito pools for authentication on the mobile app but for the mutation I want to use api-keys (IAM roles seemed to be even more complicated like [here](https://adrianhall.github.io/cloud/2018/10/26/backend-graphql-trigger-appsync/)). That is why I created an api-key inside appsync and used the following code on the lambda:

```
import requests
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Replace with your AppSync API endpoint
    endpoint = 'https://xxxxx.appsync-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/graphql'

    # Replace with your API key
    api_key = 'abcdefgh'

    # Replace with your mutation query
    mutation_query = '''
        mutation {
            createSensorData(input: {dataType: "temperature", device: "mk3", option: "", timestamp: 1592331111, value: 15.11}) {
    id
  }
        }
    '''

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-api-key': api_key
    }

    # Send the mutation request to the AppSync API
    response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, data=json.dumps({'query': mutation_query}))

    # Check the response status code
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        # Handle the response data as per your requirements
        print(data)
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(data)
        }
    else:
        error_message = f"Mutation failed with status code {response.status_code}"
        print(error_message)
        return {
            'statusCode': response.status_code,
            'body': json.dumps({'error': error_message})
        }
```

Response:

> "body": "{"data": {"createSensorData": null}, "errors": [{"path": ["createSensorData"], "data": null, "errorType": "Unauthorized", "errorInfo": null, "locations": [{"line": 3, "column": 13, "sourceName": null}], "message": "Not Authorized to access createSensorData on type Mutation"}]}"

I added the "AWSAppSyncInvokeFullAccess" policy to the lambda function, but still does not work.
The schema:

```
type Mutation {
    createSensorData(input: CreateSensorDataInput!, condition: ModelSensorDataConditionInput): SensorData
        @aws_iam
@aws_cognito_user_pools
    updateSensorData(input: UpdateSensorDataInput!, condition: ModelSensorDataConditionInput): SensorData
        @aws_iam
@aws_cognito_user_pools
    deleteSensorData(input: DeleteSensorDataInput!, condition: ModelSensorDataConditionInput): SensorData
        @aws_iam
@aws_cognito_user_pools
}
```

I am anticipating that probably the API statement is missing? But what would be the correct way? @aws_api_key? could not find this anywhere.
What else could be going wrong here?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I have a similar requirement...